NDSolve methods used in Mathematica
I have been using Mathematica for a while now primarily to solve differential equations numerically. I recently switched to Julia programming because the NDSolve option in Mathematica is quite time-consuming when handling higher dimensional differential equations. However, I am trying to determine which method Mathematica chooses to solve these equations. How can I find this information? Is it something that Mathematica does not share publically?
Any useful suggestions are welcome.

some of this is given on this page NDSolveIntroductoryTutorial  starting at NDSolve has several different methods built in for computing solutions as well as a mechanism for adding additional methods  see also what-method-does-ndsolve-use-for-solving-pdes  ...

.... see also how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected .and also inspecting-step-size-and-order-of-tt-ndsolve   Did you find Julia faster than Mathematica in numerical solving of ode's and pde's ?  Could you give one such example? That will be interesting to see. I do not use Julia myself much. But I did play with it in the past.

The introduction is part of this series, which contains discussions of many of the methods available: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html
